# $n^6+18n$ is a perfect square if and only if $n=2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, alternative-proof

> Let $n\in \mathbb{N}.$ Show that $n^6+18n$ is a perfect square if and only if $n=2$

**My Solution:**

For $n=1, n^6+18n = 19$ which is not a perfect square.

For $n=2, n^6+18n=2^6+18\cdot 2=100$ is a perfect square

We observe that for $n>2,$ $$18n<2n^3+1$$

which implies that $$n^6<n^6+18n<n^6+2n^3+1$$
$$\implies (n^3)^2<n^6+18n<(n^3+1)^2$$
$$\implies n^3<\sqrt{n^6+18n}<n^3+1$$

which implies that $\;\sqrt{n^6+18n}\;$ is a non-integer. Q.E.D

---

Can anyone think of an alternative argument rather than this proof which I find very hard to motivate?

Comment: What you did is exactly what I would have done, and it's a standard technique in solutions to diophantine equations.  The basic idea (for the motivation question) is that $n^6 + 18n$ is "too close" to another square $n^6 = (n^3)^2$ to be a perfect square itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $\;n^6+18n=k^2\;$ where $\;n,k\in\Bbb N\;,\;$ then

$n^3<k\;$ and $\;(k+n^3)(k-n^3)=18n\;,\;$ hence,

$2n^3\!\!\!\!\!\underset{\overbrace{\text{because}\\\;n^3<k}}{<}\!\!\!k+n^3\leqslant18n\;,\;$ consequently,

$n^2<9\;,\;$ that is, $\;\color{blue}{n=1}\;$ or $\;\color{blue}{n=2}\,.$

By inspection we get that only for $\,n=2\,,\;$ the number $\;n^6+18n\;$ is a perfect square.

Answer (score 2):

Another way .

---

We check $\thinspace n=1,2$ . Then, let $m\in\mathbb N^{+}$ and assuming that $n≥3$, we have $n^6+18n>3^4=81$, which leads to :

$$
\begin{align}&\left(n^3+\frac {9}{n^2}\right)^2-\left(\frac {9}{n^2}\right)^2=m^2\\
\implies &\left(n^5+9\right)^2-81=\left(mn^2\right)^2\\
\implies &\underbrace{\left(\color{red}{n^5}+mn^2+9\right)}_{\color{red}{>3^5}>81}\left(n^5-mn^2+9\right)=81\end{align}
$$

A contradiction .